# Best way to plot 9 graphs on the same plot?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Trying to make a histogram of all the predictor values in the Glass dataset. I initially used `par(mfrow=c(3,3))` to plot all 9 predictors on the same window, but got an error that the margins were too large. That's okay. Writing hist(Glass$X) nine times would've been inefficient anyway.

So then I tried to plot them all at once. I subset the data so that only the numeric columns remained, but got an error saying that they weren't numeric. I've already verified all columns are numeric. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(mlbench)
data(Glass)
library(lattice)

par(mfrow=c(3,3))
hist(Glass$RI)

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Glass2=subset(Glass[1:9])
hist(Glass2)

> Error in hist.default(Glass2) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse alternative.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(mlbench)

data(Glass)

Glass %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Type) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  facet_wrap(~name, 
             ncol = 3, 
             scales = "free")
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Subset the data into a new data frame, X. Instead of typing out X$x nine times, use a for loop. Make sure your plot window is really big or you'll get an error that the margins are too small.

```
X <- Glass[,1:9]
par(mfrow = c(3, 3))
for (i in 1:ncol(X)) {
  hist(X[ ,i], xlab = names(X[i]), main = paste(names(X[i]), "Histogram"), col="steelblue")  
}
```